# Vulkan instance creation fails

Tags: c++, graphics, gpu, vulkan

I have a vulkan program that is running on my laptop but fails on my desktop. The error is:

```
HeatMethod: ../libraries/vulkansdk-linux/1.2.154.0/source/Vulkan-Headers/include/vulkan/vulkan.hpp:13143: typename vk::ResultValueType<vk::UniqueHandle<Type, Dispatch> >::type vk::createResultValue(vk::Result, T&, const char*, const typename vk::UniqueHandleTraits<Type, Dispatch>::deleter&) [with T = vk::Instance; D = vk::DispatchLoaderStatic; typename vk::ResultValueType<vk::UniqueHandle<Type, Dispatch> >::type = vk::ResultValue<vk::UniqueHandle<vk::Instance, vk::DispatchLoaderStatic> >; typename vk::UniqueHandleTraits<Type, Dispatch>::deleter = vk::ObjectDestroy<vk::NoParent, vk::DispatchLoaderStatic>]: Assertion `result == Result::eSuccess' failed.
```

I used comments to track down the problem and found that it happens upon instance creation:

```
// Global scope
const std::vector<const char*> VALIDATION_LAYERS = {
    "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation",
};

   // Setup general information about the current application
    vk::ApplicationInfo program_info(
        "Vulkan Engine",
        VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0),
        "No Engine",
        VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0),
        VK_API_VERSION_1_2);

    if(!CheckAvailableLayers())
        RecordLogError("Validation layers requested, but not available!");

    vector<const char*> required_extensions;
    if(!RequestExtensions(required_extensions))
        RecordLogError("Missing a required extension");
    // Create Vulkan instance to communicate with the loader
    vk::InstanceCreateInfo createInfo(
        {},
        &program_info,
        static_cast<uint32_t>(VALIDATION_LAYERS.size()),
        VALIDATION_LAYERS.data(),
        static_cast<uint32_t>(required_extensions.size()),
        required_extensions.data());
    auto [result, instance] = vk::createInstanceUnique(createInfo);
```

The error itself is a failed asseriton in the hpp header, so it's kinda cryptic. I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Perhaps the obvious question first : can your desktop run other vulkan programs?

Comment: I have only tested vulkan info, but that does run without issue.

Comment: Ok, the error only says your `VkResult` is not `VK_SUCESS`, so which error code did you get instead?

Comment: Also use updated SDK. If it is some problem with the vkhpp, then while we ponder it here it might have been long ago fixed.

Comment: ErrorLayerNotPresent

Comment: I am using the latest SDK

Comment: 1.2.135 is not latest SDK. `LAYER_NOT_PRESENT` means one of the layers you requested is not supported. So I guess your environment does not see the `VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation`. Have you set `VULKAN_SDK` as it says in the [docs](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.2.154.0/linux/getting_started.html)?

Comment: I made sure to be using version 1.2.154. Before I had copypasted from the first log where this started to manifest rather than the latest, that's why the version was wrong. 

I did follow the instructions on the vulkan pages again to make sure and ran setup_env.sh, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was trying to set the validation layers on a build script:

`os.environ['VK_INSTANCE_LAYERS'] = 'VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation'`

Deleting that line solved the issue.